# MPI gather returns results in wrong order

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to multiply matrix by matrix (A*B) with an MPI. I'm splitting matrix B into columns B = [b1, ... bn] and do series of multiplications ci = A*bi. The problem is, then I'm gathering the resulting columns they order sometimes appears to be wrong. So, instead of 
[c1, ... cn] I'm getting, for example, [c2,c1,c4, ..].

```
MPI_Scatter(matrix,MM,MPI_INT,part_of_matrix,MM,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

for (i=0; i<n; i++)  {
    get_block_of_matrix(block,part_of_matrix,M,n,i);
    matvect(tmp,val,I,J,M,nnz,block);
    for (j=0; j<M; j++)
        result[M*i+j]=tmp[j];
}


MPI_Gather(result, MM, MPI_INT, res, MM, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not apparent from the code snippet above. Looking at the full source code leads me to the function `takevect`. The indexing inside is wrong, it should be like that:

```
void takevect(int *temp,int *matr, int size1, int size2, int i) {
   int j;
   for (j=0; j<size1; j++) temp[j]=matr[size1*i+j];
}
```

You are lucky when using 1 process, because `size1` equals `size2` (and `matr` is symmetric).
As can be seen, `size2` isn't needed anymore.

Furthermore, you could remove this function completely and shorten things as follows:

```
MPI_Scatter(S,MM,MPI_INT,buf_S,MM,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

for (i=0; i<local_n; i++)
   matvect(buf_res+i*M,val,I,J,M,nnz,buf_S+i*M);

MPI_Gather(buf_res, MM, MPI_INT, res, MM, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing is off.  This line:

```
 result[M*i+j]=tmp[j];
```

should read

```
 result[n*i+j]=tmp[j];
```

Comment: I think the indexing is right, this works with mpirun np=1 correctly but shows wrong results with other values of np. This is full code, it slightly longer so I didn't included it is the post http://dpaste.com/2DHG44R